# Set permanent command-line options to upstart

Tags: grub2, upstart

I would like to add a command-line option, such as `--default-console=none`, to upstart.

I believe I can just add these to the kernel invocation line and they will be passed on, is this true?  If so, how do I do this so that it will be used when grub.cfg is auto-updated because of a kernel upgrade?

If not, how do I add options directly to upstart?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit `/etc/default/grub` and add `--default-console=none` to the `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` line.

So the `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` line should look something like this:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="... --default-console=none"
```

Then run the following to regenerate your `grub.cfg`:

```
sudo grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg
```

If you need to rollback, for any reason, removing the `--default-console=none` from `/etc/default/grub` and then running `grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg` as root should be enough to take you back to how your Grub was before you made the changes.