# Long boot time on Samsung 850 EVO 500GB SSD

Tags: boot

I just installed Ubuntu 18.04 LTS  on my ASUS ROG Laptop G750JM (Linux 4.15.0-22-generic #24-Ubuntu SMP Wed May 16 12:15:17 UTC 2018) x86-64

Seems really slow on boot and launching applications (firefox, etc)

Startup finished in 2.785s (firmware) + 4.327s (loader) + 36.264s (kernel) + 15.546s (userspace) = 58.923s
graphical.target reached after 15.540s in userspace

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Try `systemd-analyze blame`

Answer (score 1):

**Slow boot**

Slow boot may be caused by [this bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubiquity/+bug/1768230). If you don't need hibernation, this bug can be worked around by adding `noresume` to the kernel command line (see [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/452300/454520) for how to change the kernel command line).

**Performance**

The performance of your SSD can be easily tested using `gnome-disks`.

1. Make sure it is installed

   `sudo apt-get install gnome-disk-utility`
2. Start `gnome-disks` (named *Disks* in the menu).
3. Select your disk on the left
4. Click on the gear wheels, select *Benchmark partition...*
5. Click on *Start Benchmark...*
6. Keep the default options, then `Start Benchmarking...`

This kind of disk should show around 500 MB/s in read speed and around 0.1 ms for the access time, if not you may have a configuration problem, maybe the SATA controller mode should be set to AHCI in the BIOS.

If the disk performances are correct, and you still feel a performance problem, it may be not related to your disk.